# Setting up Membership/Login using Visual Web Developer & ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-membership, visual-web-developer

I'm following this tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/879kf95c.aspx

And there seems to be a lot of information missing. It doesn't tell me how to upload the database to my server etc. I remember following this tutorial last year, and ran into numerous propblems, and a google search revealed THOUSANDS of people who've experienced the same problems.

I'm just so confused right now I don't even know what the hell to ask anymore. So, can anybody please recommend a website other than MSDN (or possibly a different section on MSDN) where I can learn how to do this properly without a trillion roadblocks along the way?

Thank you very much
jase

Answer (score 0):

Membership is the same since version 2.0 and this is probably the best tutorial around:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

To deploy the database to a remote server, open the server explorer window in VS and use the Database Publishing Wizard:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210519000239/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050907-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you van Visual Studio or SQL Management Studio installed and know the connectionstring you can connect to your remote database. This following article shows how to generated the needed sql scripts to execute in your remote database. [Create Membership tables in another database than the standard aspnetdb.mdf](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/CreateMembershipTablesInAnotherDatabaseThanTheStandardAspnetdbmdf.aspx).